# C# Traverse dataGridView to find null value and place "0" instead

Tags: c#, datagridview, null

I would like to traverse all the values found in the dataGridView, check if that value is null and if it is null then place a "0" value so that it would not be null. Can you please assist?

```
for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1); j++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.Equals("0");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've got? All you're missing is that you need to check 2 other conditions. Value.ToString == "" and possibly Value == DBNull.Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == System.DBNull.Value)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value="0";
}
```

as condition for checking null values in `DataGridView`. If you need you may check for `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 way you can show "0" instead of null or empty value:

**first one** is updating the DataSource before bind it to DataGrid

**second one** is using below code

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if(cell.Value == null ||  cell.Value.ToString() == string.Empty)
                {
                    cell.Value = "0";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
 {
      foreach (DataGridViewCell item in row.Cells)
      {
           if(item.Value == null || item.Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Value.ToString()))
           {
               item.Value = "0";
           }
      }              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mssql then you can check value of your columns in your query before binding to the grid.

```
SELECT ISNULL(column_name, 0)  from table_name
```

Returns the same type as check_expression. If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression, returns the datatype of the replacement_value. If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression and no replacement_value is provided, returns an int.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution:**
If you retrieve data from database then null value replace as 0 in database end, use Isnull function like this
select Isnull(columnname,0) from table
**Second Solution:**
Use GridView.RowDataBound Event
void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      if(e.Row.Cells["use cell id"].Text == null)
 
      {
         e.Row.Cells["use cell id"].Text = "0";
      }
    }
  }